# signalr js client method invoke only if page is reload manually in angular js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, signalr

i am using simple signalr in angular js to notify user , but client method invokes only if i refresh page , i have server method in webapi

startup.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(signalRTest.Startup))]
namespace signalRTest
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                };
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

hub class

```
public class ContactHub : Hub
    {
      public void UserRideRequested(int id)
        {
              Clients.All.notifyUsers(id);
        }
   }
```

client side --

```
index.html

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost:1526/signalr/hubs"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="ApplicationModule">
<div ng-view class="slide">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var contactNotifyUsers = undefined;
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:1526/signalr';
    contactNotifyUsers = $.connection.contactHub;    
    </script>

</body>
```

controller to send id to server

```
var AdminController = function ($scope,$route) {
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:1526/signalr';
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                contactNotifyUsers.server.userRideRequested(rideId);                
                $route.reload();
            });
}
```

controller for client

```
var UserController = function ($scope, $location, $http) {
  $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:1526/signalr';
        contactNotifyUsers.client.notifyUsers = function (id) {
            OpenModalForRideResponse.checkModal(id);
        };
  $.connection.hub.start();
}
```

this code works perfectly when i reload page otherwise it shows no error or any effect

Answer (score 0):

Because your mapping in the Owin `Startup.CS` will not run until the app route is actually branched (hit). I'm not sure if you are trying something special, but is enough to configure it like below:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(signalRTest.Startup))]
namespace signalRTest
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

By default SignalR will map ther request to `/signalr`

Comment: hello , thanks for answer but this gives error 

Protocol error: Unknown transport.

Comment: In the javascript?

Comment: Sorry, was a bit fast. Please try the `app.MapSignalR()` instead.

Comment: tried that only map will sure give error , app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
app.RunSignalR();

Comment: it is giving this in log if you have any idea "SignalR: No hubs have been subscribed to. The client will not receive data from hubs. To fix, declare at least one client side function prior to connection start for each hub you wish to subscribe to."